# Should we be referring more questions to https://quant.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion

I have no idea where people draw the line, but many of the recent questions about "how do I calculate this investment number" strike me as being a better fit there than here, since they're based on the assumption that the formula has some predictive value and to me that means quant.

Basic stuff like apr and history is within our remit. I'm not convinced anything much deeper is.

But I'm not convinced it isn't either.

It's all fractals and fuzz at the dividing line, but we should be able to at least state a principle, and maybe publish it so folks know which stack to start in before being redirected.

Comment: [What is on-topic at Quant SE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might also inform this discussion, otherwise we might create a wide chasm when that perhaps isn't what is intended.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, addressing the general question of whether questions should be redirected at all, particularly if they've already been posted on one site.

There's a [good network-wide answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/132930) about this, and I'm reproducing the key flowchart here:

[image: When should I vote to migrate a question?]

Many questions that might seem too esoteric for this site still won't be a good fit for quant, regardless of that. Judging from the comments, [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/154922/what-are-alternatives-to-black-scholes-model-that-doesnt-assume-random-walk-beh) is a good example of that.

Overall, I would recommend focusing on what's good for this site and not so much on what might or might not fit elsewhere. There'll be a chasm regardless of any boundary we draw here.

Comment: Ok. I am not convinced that the statistics are in fact good for this site, but that may be my own cynicism about whether they have any value at all.

Comment: @keshlam I'm not at all sure where to draw the line, I just wanted to debunk the common assumption that we can just define a certain class of things that we don't want here and can also send to quant. Best to make our own decisions about what fits here.

Comment: Reality is fractal and/or fuzzy, no completely sharp edges, etc. ... But that's part of why these decisions are voted on.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that, for better or for worse, Quant is basically Quant Overflow. I believe there is a middle ground between the personal finance that is on-topic here and the high-level quantitative finance that is required to be on-topic there that is not covered by the Stack Exchange network (maybe by Economics).

Comment: It's just so damned hard for those of us who don't share that mindset to judge where to draw even a fuzzy line.  And to resist responding dismissively. Oh well, I'll manage.